# Use TAP with wcf EAP generated proxies

Tags: c#, silverlight, async-await

I have a Silverlight 5 app, that makes use of a WCF service. The proxy client that has been generated has only asychronous methods (by default, when generating from the SL client).

I want to make use of the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP), now within VS2012RC.

What is the best approach to consume the async methods from the generated client proxy ?

(the issue is, that the WCF proxy generator creates code that is based on the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP) and not TAP....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this document:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957

I have found a solution for this.

See code below:

```
public class MyDataListProvider : IMyDataListProvider
{
    private <ObservableCollection<IMyData>> myDataList;

    public Task<ObservableCollection<IMyData>> GetMyData()
            {
                TaskCompletionSource<ObservableCollection<IMyData>> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<ObservableCollection<IMyData>>();

                MyWCFClientProxy client = new MyWCFClientProxy();

                this.myDataList.Clear();

                client.GetMyDataCompleted += (o, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Error != null)
                    {
                        taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(e.Error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (e.Cancelled)
                        {
                            taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (var s in e.Result)
                            {
                                var item = new MyData();
                                item.Name = s.Name;
                                item.Fullname = s.Fullname;

                                this.myDataList.Add(item);
                            }

                            taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(this.myDataList);
                        }
                    }
                };

                client.GetMyDataAsync();

                return taskCompletionSource.Task;
            }
}
```

Client SL code:

```
private async void SetMyDataList()
        {
            this.MyDataList = await this.myDataListProvider.GetMyData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it was available in the RC, however as of the SDK 8.0A (the one included with VS2012) `svcutil.exe` will generate async methods using the TAP pattern.

It will use TAP by default so be sure to **NOT** include `/async` as that will make it fall back to the old APM method of generating the methods.

You can see if the version of `svcutil` is new enough to use the TAP by looking at the first lines of the program it will include that it is at least version 4.0 of the tool.

> Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation, Version **4.0**.xxxxx.xxxxxx]