# How can I wait for an async WCF service method to complete?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1

I have two methods in my WCF Service:

```
public interface IPriceService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "GetPrice")]
    decimal GetPrice(long ID);

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetProductID")]
    long GetProductID(string productName);
}
```

On a cliect side I want to do two things. I want to call a method `GetProductID` and then call a method `GetPrice`. So I do it like this:

```
PriceService.PriceServiceClient service;
service = new PriceService.PriceServiceClient();
service.PobierzPrzejsciaCompleted += service_GetPriceCompleted;
service.PobierzStacjeBenzynoweCompleted += service_GetProductIDCompleted;

service.GetProductIDAsync(productName);
service.GetPriceAsync(Id);
```

`GetProductID` returns an ID, so I get it in `GetProductIDCompleted` event. Then I pass this ID as a parameter to `GetPrice` method.

What I want is: **`GetProductIdAsync` method should execute first. `GetPriceAsync` method should wait until previous method completes.**

Comment: Are they `awaitable`? Why not `await service.GetProductIDAsync(productName);`?

Comment: Implement [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx). Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15316613/2681948) will help.

Comment: I don't have available "Generate task-based operations" in Windows Phone 8.1 while adding service reference.

Comment: Build a Task in which you define TCS, then subscribe to your service event, in the complete delegate set result for TCS, return TCS.Task. Then await your new Task. It's [converting EAP to TAP - example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11450287/2681948).

Comment: Oh thanks you. But it's really hard to understand for me...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have them executed synchronous, you can also simply use the synchronous versions:

```
var productId = service.GetProductID(productName)
var price = service.GetPrice(productId)
```

our if you would like to stick on the async calls, you can call the `service.GetPriceAsync` function from the `service_GetProductIDCompleted` completed function...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BackgroundWorker object and then subscribe to the run worker completed event. In that event you would be able to run it.

So something like

```
Worker.RunWorkerAsync()
Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += youractionwhencompletedmethod
```